# How to fix nested asn1 error in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Whenever I try to run my code with `discord.py` package i get some nested asn1 error. Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "epic")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

client.run('NzcxMDIxMjQyNDk2MzE5NTQ4.X5mDfQ.chrdyrxO6OBcQOPRKTIhw05eeAc')
```

Also, here is the error i get:

> Message=[ASN1] nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:4145)
> Source=C:\Users\Vesna\source\repos\DiscordBot\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.py
> StackTrace:   File
> "C:\Users\Vesna\source\repos\DiscordBot\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.py",
> line 10, in 
> client.run('NzcxMDIxMjQyNDk2MzE5NTQ4.X5mDfQ.chrdyrxO6OBcQOPRKTIhw05eeAc')

Comment: Still no answers...

Answer (score 1):

That nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:4145) indicates there is an issue communicating with the server. More than likely, you have a bad CA Root certificate.

1. Go to start, type internet explorer. Run as admin.
2. Go to discord.com click on the padlock icon.
3. Click view certificates
4. Click install certificates, choose either user or local machine.
5. Click Place all certificates in the following store
6. Choose Trusted Root Certification Authorities

You may also inspect the certificate chain with: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect discordapp.com:443`

You may also want to regenerate that bot token within the Discord Application interface, as sharing it could allow others to use your bot.

Comment: Tried it and still nothing, i get the same error message.

Comment: Can you try regenerating the bot token within the Discord Application interface? If that does not work, reinstall discord.py with `pip install -U discord.py` That  nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:4145) indicates there is an issue communicating with the server. More than likely, you have a bad CA Root certificate. If neither of these work, you will need to do some digging to find the bad cert. What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 7 32bit

Comment: 1) Go to start, type internet explorer. Run as admin.
2) Go to https://discord.com click on the padlock icon.
3) Click view certificates
4) Click install certificates, choose either user or local machine.
5) Click Place all certificates in the following store
6) Choose Trusted Root Certification Authorities

Comment: Tried it and still nothing. Also, i checked few websites and I got the information that certs from my region (Balkan) are really bad and that they can be fixed by doing some steps. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: I can't speak to certs in the balkans, but try this: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect discordapp.com:443`

Comment: Problem solved! It was due to bad certification. Thank you man.

Comment: @Epic. Cool. If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted and upvote so anyone else with the same issue sees it.